# how to recognize in javascript dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

Is there any way to take a JavaScript string such as

```
"program[one] = js"
```

and run on this string and make it accessible so that when I type

```
console.log(program.one);
```

I will get `js`

Comment: where is your `program` variable defined?

Comment: Sounds like you want `evil`, I mean `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval` method (although it is not highly recommanded) and do something like this:

```
var program = {};

var str = "program['one'] = 'js'";

eval(str);

console.log(program.one);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want to allow the string to write in `program` and that the only valid strings are of the form `program[name] = value` there is a not evil solution:

```
var program = {};

var input = "program[one] = js";

var patt = /program\[(.*?)\] = (.*)/;
var result = patt.exec(input); // Array [ "program[one] = js", "one", "js" ]

program[result[1]] = result[2];

console.log(program.one); // js
```

Edit: you may have to tweak the regular expression (`patt`) if you need to support quotes, and ending semicolon.

---

Using [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785959/402022) is [considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) [harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea). If you are not in control of the string passed to it - which often is the case - it could run any code allowing for code injection. *No, do not pretend you can do what I did above for arbitrary programs*. On the other hand, if you are in control of the string, you shouldn't need eval - although I accept it may be practical if you are using [metaprogramming by code generation in javascript](http://blog.berniesumption.com/software/eval-considered-useful/).

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this backwards.

What you want is some JSON that represents a JS object that you can parse.

```
var json = '{"program":{"one": "js"}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

obj.program.one // js
```

Even if you're not thinking about this backwards you *do* need to go back and work out *why* you need to use a string like "program[one] = js" because the approach is wrong-headed and will only lead to heartache.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2kt7of2t/)